# JavaEE - InvalidClassException

Tags: java, class, exception, jakarta-ee, java-ee-7

I'm writing a JavaEE application and I have the following problem: if I initialize any new variable in one of the classes (TraceMessage) and start the application, I am getting the following error:

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: com.nsn.extmon.util.TraceMessage; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -5424907704652912574, local class serialVersionUID = -5748024201087063218
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:612)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1630)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1521)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1779)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:771)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor355.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1907)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1806)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
at com.nsn.extmon.databaseHandling.ResultDataHandler.getTraceMessages(ResultDataHandler.java:137)
at com.nsn.extmon.util.TraceResultBean.traceRead(TraceResultBean.java:50)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.invoke(ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.java:96)
at org.apache.myfaces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:72)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:120)
at org.richfaces.component.RowKeyContextEventWrapper.broadcast(RowKeyContextEventWrapper.java:104)
at org.richfaces.component.UIDataAdaptor.broadcast(UIDataAdaptor.java:452)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._broadcastAll(UIViewRoot.java:1013)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:284)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._process(UIViewRoot.java:1302)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:745)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationExecutor.execute(InvokeApplicationExecutor.java:38)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:170)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:117)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:197)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at com.nsn.extmon.authentication.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:33)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:611)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:409)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1044)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1721)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1679)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have no idea what this error is, I only know that if I modify variable names, then everything is working fine. The error only comes up when I'm declaring new variables.

Thanks in advice.

Comment: A look at some code sample would help understand this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `InvalidClassException` class exception occurs in this situation when you deserialise (receiving, loading, etc) an object into a java process that has a *different* version of the class as the one used during serialisation (sending, saving, etc) .

It looks like you are saving objects into the database (`com.nsn.extmon.databaseHandling.ResultDataHandler`?). I think there are serialised blobs in the database serialised with a different version of the class ("adding fields") then when you read them from the database again.

If you are adding fields, you should keep the `serialVersionUID` the same (for ***non*** contract-breaking changes)

For Example

```
public class TraceMessage implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  …
}
```

If it is a **contract-breaking** change, then you must make sure you have the same class version on both ends.

if you are sending messages between applications, then you might also want to look in a less brittle protocol such as google protobuf.

EDIT (see comments): If you want to load the old classes stored in your database with the new class, then set your `serialVersionUID` to `-5424907704652912574`

Comment: It is just submiting and reading data from the database, I tried to add  `private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;` but then I get the following error: `java.io.InvalidClassException: com.nsn.extmon.util.TraceMessage; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -5424907704652912574, local class serialVersionUID = 1`. I understand that the already serialized objects ID stays the same.

Comment: You need to do some migration work: You probably still have objects in the database written with older version of your class. You have to either load them with the old class files, or set your `serialVersionUID` to `-5424907704652912574`.

Comment: I changed the ID to -5424907704652912574 and it is working now. Thank you very much. :)